# Facebook API login -logging

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was looking at logging all the users that entered the website using FB .with the help of purushotam ( see my other question)  was able to proceed.

here are my new issues:
1) how can I get/use the facebook provided button. Reason is I want user to get the same user experience. (facebook button bluish button)
2) once the user logs in than , I want to send a alert and than go to the website I re-directed (in example I have stackoverflow).  Because FB is non blocking asynchronous, I see before the FB returns the value the website is getting redirected. how to resolve this issue.
3) When a user tries to login I dont want the FB popup- I want to have the FB login in a new page (just like stackoverflow login) how can I do that ..

```
  <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({appId: 'xxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());

    function fetchUserDetail()
    {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                alert("Name: "+ response.name + "\nFirst name: "+ response.first_name + "ID: "+response.id);
            });
        window.location.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';  
    }

    function checkFacebookLogin() 
    {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            fetchUserDetail();
          } 
          else 
          {
            initiateFBLogin();
          }
         });
    }

    function initiateFBLogin()
    {
        FB.login(function(response) {
           fetchUserDetail();
         });
    }
    </script>


 <input type="button" value="Sign in using Facebook" onclick="checkFacebookLogin();"/>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) how can I get/use the facebook provided button. Reason is I want user to get the same user experience. (facebook button bluish button)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/, 
https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php

> 2) once the user logs in than , I want to send a alert and than go to the website I re-directed (in example I have stackoverflow). Because FB is non blocking asynchronous, I see before the FB returns the value the website is getting redirected. how to resolve this issue.

Sorry, I don’t really get what you’re asking here. Please try to be more specific.

> 3) When a user tries to login I dont want the FB popup- I want to have the FB login in a new page (just like stackoverflow login) how can I do that ..

Don’t use FB.login then, but redirect the user to the URL of the Auth dialog; see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/#no-jssdk

Comment: Thank you for the reply regarding 2) If you run the program (code in the question). you will see that the userAlert is not  executed. it directly goes to stackoverflow.I want to have the alert printed than go to stackoverflow website.regarding 3) the FB example we have window.open and the FB pages opens in a new window..I want the same page to be directed FB ..once authenticated it should come back (same user experience like that of a stackoverflow)

Comment: _“you will see that the userAlert is not executed. it directly goes to stackoverflow.”_ – well of course it does, because FB.api is an _asynchronous_ method – code execution does not “wait” until it is done, but goes on straight away.

Comment: yes that is the issue and my question is :-). I want the user to login into my website using FB login. once they login I want to take a note into my DB (all the pages inside changes according to the user who loged in). at the same time oncehe is authenticated I want to go inside my portal (in this case stack overflow.com).I understand it is asynchronous how to get around this problem...I know many people are using FB login . how are the addessing this problem

Comment: Put whatever you want executed when the method is done with it’s work inside the callback function.

Comment: Thanks that resolved only 80%of my problem. I have two FB.api's . one I am using for getting fb.api(/me) and another fb.api(me/friends) after which call back should I keep. the reason is if I keep that in fb.api(friends) than only fb.api is getting called and the page is redirected. If I keep in fb.api(/me) it works. But you answered the question I have I will raise that as a new question